# Using factory_girl within a rake task - getting uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, factory, factory-bot

I'm trying to use Factory Girl in a rake task like this:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require File.expand_path("spec/factories.rb")

namespace :users do

  desc "Create sample users for use in development" 
  task :create_sample_users => :environment do
    Factory(:user, :email => "pending@acme.com")
    Factory(:approved_user, :email => "user@acme.com") 
  end

end
```

However when I run `rake users:create_sample_users` I get the error `uninitialized constant Entry` (Entry is the name of one of my app's classes).

Can anyone tell me how to get Factory girl to see my classes?  It's working fine in my tests, just failing in my rake tasks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing that Rails hasn't loaded your models at the point you are requiring the factories.  Try this:

```
require 'factory_girl'

namespace :users do

  desc "Create sample users for use in development" 
  task :create_sample_users => :environment do
    require File.expand_path("spec/factories.rb")
    Factory(:user, :email => "pending@acme.com")
    Factory(:approved_user, :email => "user@acme.com") 
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks - that has sorted it!  As a bonus, do you know where I could put `require File.expand_path("spec/factories.rb")` so I don't have to include it in every task?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For `factory_bot` which has replaced `factory_girl` use:

```
require 'factory_bot'

namespace :users do

  desc "Create sample users for use in development" 
  task :create_sample_users => :environment do
    include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

    create(:user, :email => "pending@acme.com")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@dmcnally's answer didn't work for me, as I was getting odd errors of constants not found. Instead, I resolved it by shelling out to rails runner:

```
sh "rails runner 'FactoryGirl.create :user'"
```